# How to replace ™ in a string?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, unicode, python-unicode

I have a string looks like this: Getting Started with NetX™ DHCP rev1.05

I want to replace TM with %E2%84%A2.

I added:# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- to the very top of the file, still not work, no errors pop up

I am using Python 2.7

Here's my python code:

```
def create_link(title):
  temp_title = title.replace(' ', '%20') # first replace space with %20. works fine
  temp_title.replace('™', '%E2%84%A2') # then replace TM, not working
  link = 'https://ApplicationNotes/'+ temp_title
  return link
```

Comment: Python 2 or 3? This is a key detail

Comment: FWIW, Python already comes with [utilities to escape URLs](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote), no need to do it manually

Comment: Python 2.7. Thanks!

Comment: Does [`urllib.quote(title)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote) work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The replacement does not work because for the second call to `str.replace()` the return value is not assigned to anything, so it is lost. You could fix it with:

```
temp_title = temp_title.replace('™', '%E2%84%A2')
```

to bind the return value to `temp_title`, however, consider the following.

Since you want to percent encode the string for use in a URL you can simply use [`urlib.quote()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote):

```
>>> title = 'NetX™ DHCP rev1.05'
>>> title
'NetX\xe2\x84\xa2 DHCP rev1.05'
>>> import urllib    # Python 2
>>> urllib.quote(title)
'NetX%E2%84%A2%20DHCP%20rev1.05'
```

You'll notice that the spaces have also been handled for you. So you could write your function like this:

```
def create_link(title):
    return urllib.quote('https://ApplicationNotes/{}'.format(title))
```

which has the advantage of also percent encoding other eligible characters in the URL.

For completeness, if you were using Python 3:

```
>>> from urllib.parse import quote
>>> quote('NetX™ DHCP rev1.05')
'NetX%E2%84%A2%20DHCP%20rev1.05'
```

---

You might not even need to quote URL depending on what you want to do with it. If you are using `requests` to send a HTTP request for the URL you can just use it as is:

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get('https://ApplicationNotes/NetX™ DHCP rev1.05')
>>> r.url
u'https://ApplicationNotes/NetX%E2%84%A2%20DHCP%20rev1.05'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you use `re` module:

```
import re
def create_link(title):
  temp_title = title.replace(' ', '%20') # first replace space with %20. works fine
  temp_title = re.sub(r'™', r'%E2%84%A2', temp_title) # this change
  link = 'https://ApplicationNotes/'+ temp_title
  return link
```

Answer (score 0):

I used python 3.4 and this code works for me. please change line 3 to  `temp_title = temp_title.replace('™', '%E2%84%A2')`

```
def create_link(title):
    temp_title = title.replace(' ', '%20')
    temp_title = temp_title.replace('™', '%E2%84%A2')
    link = 'https://ApplicationNotes/'+ temp_title
    return link
```